# Super slow performance between Umbraco and AWS S3 bucket for images and cached images (ImageProcessor)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, umbraco, aws-sdk, imageprocessor

So I've been having really slow performance site when it comes to image loading, resizing and the lot using the ImageProcessor within Umbraco.

Currently using:

- Umbraco 7.4.3
- AWSSDK.Core 3.3.11
- AWSSDK.S3 3.3.5.11
- ImageProcessor 2.5.3
- ImageProcessor.Web 4.8.3
- Umbraco.Storage.S3 1.0.23 (not maintained anymore?)

CloudFront doesn't cache the images either (custom origin doesn't get cached from what I understand?), so to avoid the site falling over, I have an NGINX server between CloudFront and the Umbraco servers (which are behind a standard AWS load balancer).

It's hard to think that 2 x c4.xlarge instances can't cope with processing the images instantly.

One thing I noticed that happens sometimes is the following:
[Log snippet](https://paste.ofcode.org/3634KQPbfrSXX8VwWisJJzt)

I just put new pair of AWS access keys to see if it will make any difference, but sadly, still slow. Even the backoffice takes ages to load up previews of the images in both the content tab and media tab.

Configuration wise, I've triple checked against what I've found on the internet (for FileSystemProviders and ImageProcessor configs).

Imageprocessor cache config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<caching xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" currentCache="AmazonS3Cache" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <caches>
    <cache name="AmazonS3Cache" type="formula_e.web.cms.Core.ImageProcessor.AmazonS3Cache, formula-e.web.cms" maxDays="365" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <settings>
        <setting key="AwsAccessKey" value="XXXXXXX" />
        <setting key="AwsSecretKey" value="XXXXXXX" />
        <setting key="AwsBucketName" value="XXXXXXX" />
        <setting key="AwsEndpoint" value="http://XXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/" />
        <setting key="AwsBucketFolder" value="cache-live" />
        <setting key="CachedCDNRoot" value="http://XXXXXXX.cloudfront.net" />
        <setting key="StreamCachedImage" value="true" />
      </settings>
    </cache>
  </caches>
</caching>
```

Imageprocessor security config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<security xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <services xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <service prefix="media/" name="CloudImageService" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Services.CloudImageService, ImageProcessor.Web">
      <settings>
        <setting key="MaxBytes" value="41943040"/>
        <setting key="Timeout" value="30000"/>
        <setting key="Host" value="http://XXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/media/"/>
      </settings>
    </service>
  </services>
</security>
```

Filesytemproviders config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<FileSystemProviders xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <Provider alias="media" type="Umbraco.Storage.S3.BucketFileSystem, Umbraco.Storage.S3" xdt:Locator="Match(alias)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <Parameters>
      <!-- S3 Bucket Name -->
      <add key="bucketName" value="XXXXXXX" />
      <!-- S3 Bucket Hostname - Used for storage in umbraco's database (Should be blank when using Virtual File Provider) -->
      <add key="bucketHostName" value="" />
      <!-- S3 Object Key Prefix - What should we prefix keys with? -->
      <add key="bucketKeyPrefix" value="media" />
      <!-- AWS Region Endpoint (us-east-1/us-west-1/ap-southeast-2) Important to get right otherwise all API requests will return a 30x response -->
      <add key="region" value="eu-west-1" />
    </Parameters>
  </Provider>
</FileSystemProviders>
```

How do I go about finding out what the issue is?

Comment: Did you check the documentation on how to publish umbraco to CDN ?

Comment: @mootmoot Mind sharing a link? I inherited this project so I've been trying to figure out most of the setup as best as I can. Thanks

Comment: Please google `umbraco  cache AWS CDN`. CDN cache setup is not as straightforward.

Comment: Got you. Regardless of the CDN not performing perfectly, the main issue is still the preformacne between S3 and the server. The backoffice is really slow when dealing with images. To give you an example, when using the media picker in the backoffice and opening a folder with about 10 images which are like 100-200kb each, the preview would load in more than 30 seconds sometimes! I want to find out the cause of that before moving to the CDN issue.

Comment: Afraid S3 may not be the culprit, if you CMS is connect to it using S3 endpoint within the VPC. However, there is a latency when download files sequentially and process them. I'm not sure whether you CMS able to process images asynchronously

Comment: I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the way it's setup as it can start falling over with 100 concurrent users. I'm sure there are sites out there that cope with much more and use ImageProcessor with S3.

Comment: Whose cache is that? It's not official!

Comment: @JamesSouth Are you referring to currentCache="AmazonS3Cache"

Comment: @MrVentzi Yeah. I didn't write that. I only have an unfinished one in the repo. Definitely not ready for production websites. The Storage provider also has a memory leak https://github.com/ElijahGlover/Umbraco-S3-Provider/pull/11

Comment: @JamesSouth I noticed this in the config last Friday when I was doing some bits on the staging server and it seemed to load up images instantly in the back office, so I compared the two configs for release and staging, and boom, AmazonS3Cache on release and DiskCache on staging. I inherited this project, so not sure what was the reasoning for adding this. Is it safe to put DiskCache on release (setup:1xDB, 1xAdmin Server and 2xSlave servers, media files stored in S3 bucket)?

Comment: If you use DiskCache and set the VirtualCachePath outside the web root it should be good. You don't want lots of FileSystemWatcher's running. 

http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/configuration/#cacheconfig

Comment: @JamesSouth Thanks. I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: @JamesSouth It's perfect now. Down to average 100ms from average 20 seconds for single image loading (if you request different size). Thanks for confirming that was the problem!

Comment: @MrVentzi Happy to help! You should create an answer now with more specific detail on your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue, the whole problem was within the cache config file and caused the whole system to be performing really slowly when several images were requested at the same time, due to the cache of the images being in S3 rather than locally.

The cache was set to currentCache="AmazonS3Cache" which is not even official (confirmed by JamesSouth).

Once I put currentCache="DiskCache" on the production machines, everything was working as it should.